# Why Angular 2 Route fetching only single templateUrl

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have an Angular 2 application, i am just learning. i have two components with templateUrl, but route is not working, only url is coming correctly, but content is the same. please see my below codes.

**app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';
import { AppItemUnit }  from './inventory/itemUnit.component';

import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'Dashboard', component: AppComponent },
  { path: 'ItemUnit', component: AppItemUnit }
];

@NgModule ({
  imports: [ BrowserModule,HttpModule,RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)],
  declarations: [ AppComponent,AppItemUnit],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: 'views/dashboard.html',
})
export class AppComponent  { name = 'Angular'; }
```

**itemUnit.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component ({
   selector: 'my-app',
   templateUrl: 'views/itemUnit.html',
})
export class AppItemUnit  {
}
```

**index.html**

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="Dashboard">Dashboard</a></li>
    <li><a href="ItemUnit">Item Unit</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must direct to specific route, via `Router` like this:

```
<li><a routerLink="Dashboard">Dashboard</a></li>
```

Comment: there is no app.component.html

Comment: Oh, I mean, just try to move it out of the index.html - to any other `.html` file

Comment: And in index.html just place - `<my-app></my-app>`, instead of what you put in there. And all from there move into `'views/dashboard.html`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155663/discussion-between-sebu-and-incognito).